# Как программно проверить наличие установленного Adobe Reader?

Tags: c#, pdf, com, windowsinstaller

У нас в программу встроен элемент управления Adobe Reader с помощью AcroPdfLib. Если не стоит Adobe Reader, конструктор формы падает с ошибкой. Хотелось бы реализовать такое поведение: если не установлен Adobe Reader, не открывать pdf-документ в нашей программе, а предложить пользователю, сохранить его.

Еще лучшим вариантом было бы использование для отображения pdf-документов такой библиотеки, которая не требует установки чего бы то ни было, чтобы можно было просто положить сборку в дистрибутив - и всё работает.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Проверка записи в реестре:

```
RegistryKey adobe = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Adobe");

if (adobe != null)
{
    RegistryKey acrobatReader = adobe.OpenSubKey("Acrobat Reader");

    if (acrobatReader != null)
    {
        // TODO: ...
    }
}
```

Проверка GUID для инсталлятора, если GUID известны:

```
bool installed = codes.Any(guid =>
{
     var code = "{" + guid.ToString().ToUpper() + "}";
     var state = MsiQueryProductState(code);

     return state == 3 || state == 5);
});
```

Здесь codes - это guid для версий Acrobat Reader.

Варианты просмотра pdf-файлов на C# без установленного софта от Adobe:

- [View PDF files in C# using the Xpdf and muPDF library, Print PostScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37637/View-PDF-files-in-C-using-the-Xpdf-and-muPDF-libra).
- [PDF Viewer Control Without Acrobat Reader Installed](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37458/PDF-Viewer-Control-Without-Acrobat-Reader-Installed).